# Updating an object with setState in React (solidity event filter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, web3js

Is it at all possible to update the object's properties with setState?

Something like:

```
this.state = {
audit: { name: "1", age: 1 },
}
```

I can log the event to the console using:-

```
myContract.once('MyEvent', {
    filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23], myOtherIndexedParam: '0x123456789...'}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
    fromBlock: 0
}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); });
```

my solidity ABI object created  on console  is

```
App.js:42 
{logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x94f6d8671988ceb8ef1da862257637a198f4afefc3aef6cf3eb992dfcafb0eb1", blockHash: "0xd26937f8535a335663c9af57335f7cc783aba0e9e376408cbb92c1b3f1b28166", blockNumber: 20, …}
logIndex: 0
transactionIndex: 0
transactionHash: "0x94f6d8671988ceb8ef1da862257637a198f4afefc3aef6cf3eb992dfcafb0eb1"
blockHash: "0xd26937f8535a335663c9af57335f7cc783aba0e9e376408cbb92c1b3f1b28166"
blockNumber: 20
address: "0x20B40e09b75a21E0B857F695dE5De92a5A5b5AD0"
type: "mined"
id: "log_0d967aac"
returnValues: Result
0: "1"
1: "bhavin"
2: "masterpiece"
3: "1000000000000000000"
4: "100"
5: "200"
6: "blah blah blah!!"
7: "0x04f78093E2a1C07BF6c4527Aaa00807d3132A1Df"
8: false
id: "1"
Artistname: "bhavin"
Artname: "masterpiece"
price: "1000000000000000000"
width: "100"
height: "200"
Description: "blah blah blah!!"
owner: "0x04f78093E2a1C07BF6c4527Aaa00807d3132A1Df"
purchased: false
__proto__: Object
event: "Artworkcreated"
signature: "0xf912339172a3b7eda9cb10ecdef181d10a74fc4411fe5d7e62f550ef3698d845"
raw: {data: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…16820626c6168212100000000000000000000000000000000", topics: Array(4)}
__proto__: Object
```

I need to setState the required data and use it later so I am using .setState like this

```
  showusingID(ids){
      this.setState({ loading: true })
      this.state.instance.events.Artworkcreated({
           filter: { id: ids},
           fromBlock: 0,
       }).on('data', function(event){
        this.setState({...this.state.audit, name: 'someothername'});
    })
      }
```

but it showing

`.setState is not a function.`

Comment: Context binding problems ? `showusingID = ids => {`

Comment: I tried using arrow function for binding  but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'audit' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function in `on('data')`.

```
showusingID = ids => {
  this.setState({ loading: true })
  this.state.instance.events.Artworkcreated({
    filter: { id: ids},
    fromBlock: 0,
  }).on('data', event => {
    this.setState({...this.state.audit, name: 'someothername'});
  })
}
```

Comment: Where is the console.log?

Comment: Might need to use `this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, name: 'someothername'}))`.

Comment: My bad, anyways thanks for the help and a prompt reply. Your solution have helped me a lot!